# Define an injection between the Power Set of positive Integers and Set of all Total Orders on positive Integers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am doing a problem from Velleman's book " How to Prove It".

It asks to show that the Power set of pos. Integers and the set of all Total Orders on pos. Integers are equinumerous. (I intend to do this by using the Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein Theorem)
I already have an injection from the Set of Total Orders to the Power Set of pos. Integers.
The other direction is the one i am stuck with.
In a previous problem we proved that the power set of pos. integers and the set of all equivalence relations on pos. integers are equinumerous. I dont know if this fact can be used here to make the proof easier.
The hint to that exercise says to imitate the solution to the previous exercise, so here i post the previous problem:

Let $\mathcal{E} = \{R \mid \text{R is an equivalence realation on } 
\Bbb{Z}^+ \}$

a) Prove that $\mathcal{E} \precsim \mathscr{P}(\Bbb{Z}^+)$.

b) Let $A = \Bbb{Z}^+\setminus\{1,2\} \text{ and let } \mathcal{P} \text{ be the set of all partitions of } \Bbb{Z}^+.$

$\text{Define } f : \mathscr{P}(A) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}\text{ by the formula } f(X) = \{X\, \cup \, \{1\}, (A\setminus X)\,\cup\, \{2\}\}. $
Prove that f is one-to-one.

c) Prove that $\,\mathcal{E} \sim \, \mathscr{P}(\Bbb{Z}^+)$.

My problem is that in part c) we used the already proven fact that
$\,\mathcal{E} \sim \, \mathcal{P}$, but we have no such information for the set
$\mathcal{T} = \{R \, \mid \text{R is a total order on $\Bbb{Z}^+\}$}$.

I would be nice to have both solutions. One through a direct injection and one maybe with help of the set $\mathcal{P}$ or some other set.

Comment: Use a pairing bijection $p\colon \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. Different total orders will have different images under $p$.

Answer (score 0):

Given a total order $<_*$ on the positive integers, map it to the set of positive integers
$$f(<_*):=\{2^{k}(2\ell+1) \,:\, k<_*\ell\}\,.$$
This mapping $f$ is injective.

Comment: I am sorry, i meant that i already have an injection from Total order set to Power set. I need the other one. I have  corrected my question.